# Avoid sorting buttons to be clickable in the padding area

Tags: html, css, button, onclick, padding

Having the following image:

[image]

You can see that there is a blue area and a green area. It seems that the arrows for sorting are active in the green area too, when I click there the sorting is done. In this case, it should not behave like this, it should be clickable only inside the blue area.

Is it a way to do this?

```
<th colspan="1" role="columnheader" class="sortable pointer">
  Price
  <span class="sort desc"></span>
</th>
```

The green area is the padding of the element: `padding: 9px 9px 9px 8px;`

Comment: That depends on where is your onclick function. If that is within your `<th>` then it will apply for the green area. Can you show how your sort even gets triggered?

Comment: Please could you show us the CSS (and any other HTML if relevant) associated with this. For example when you say 'the green area is the padding of the element' which element is that? And which element is the event listener attached to?